# How to pass any text value from form to Crystal Report?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

How to pass any text value from form to Crystal Report ?

ex: i need to pass "hellow" from Form1 to my Crystal Report , how to do it ?

(working in C#)

thank's in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a parameter field in Crystal.  You can set its value via the parameters collection at run-time.

Comment: thank's for the help, can i get more detail's ?
I dont know how to do it

Comment: You can create the parameter in Crystal from the Field Explorer; right-click on Parameter Fields then select New.  The Crystal documentation can give you more info on creating the parameter.

This should help you get started with the C# portion: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289936(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
CrystReport1 plc = new CrystReport1();
plc.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["Formula Fild Name*"].Text = "" + textBox1.Text + "";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CrystReport1 plc = new CrystReport1();
plc.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["Formula Fild Name*"].Text = " '" + textBox1.Text + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     ReportDocument dailyIssueDocument=new ReportDocument();
   var fD = dailyIssueDocument.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["fTextBox"] as TextObject;// fTextBox is a Text object that i take to my report for showing form select date
   if (fD != null){
       fD.Text = fDate;//This is Date field that comes from  form text box
}
```